# Redirecionamento de permalinks

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um site desenvolvido em Wordpress, e a estrutura principal é:
`www.teste.com.br/titulo-do-post` só que, vou ter que modificar para:
`www.teste.com.br/categoria-do-post/titulo-do-post`

Todos os links que compartilhei como mostrado na primeira forma não irão mais funcionar, sem contar na relevância do Google. O que devo fazer?

Estou alterando aqui:
[image: SS]

Comment: como voce esta modificando a estrutura?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta.

Comment: Voce quer saber como implementar a nova estrutura ou o que vai passar com a predefenida depois de implementar?

Comment: Eu quero saber como manter os links antigos. E fazer um redirect para o link novo.

Answer (score 2):

O plugin [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) serve para gestionar redirecionamentos 301, que é o que você precisa.

Outra maneira de solucinar o problema, mas que exige maior conhecimento, é criar [Rewrite Rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) diretamente na configuração do seu site no Apache, através do arquivo `.htaccess`

Comment: Pelo que vi, eu vou ter que redirecionar link por link?

Comment: Eu particularmente gosto muito dessa solução de usar Rewrite Rules porque o desempenho é muito melhor que usar qualquer plugin ou hook no WordPress. No seu caso, fazer um "de-para" não é tão difícil.

Comment: @FelipeStoker se decidir usar o Redirection, terá que fazer link a link. A segunda solução é mais inteligente, sugiro fortemente ler a documentação do mod_rewrite do Apache e implementá-la. Abs.

Answer (score 1):

adicionar rules para as categorias:

```
add_action( 'init', 'nz_add_category_rules' );

function nz_add_category_rules() {

      $categories = get_categories( 'post' );
      $cat_slug = array();
      foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
            $cat_slug[] = $cat->slug;
      }
      $cat_regex = '(' . join( '|', $cat_slug ) . ')';
      $regex = $cat_regex . '/([^/]+)$';
      $redirect = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]';


      add_rewrite_rule( $regex, $redirect, 'top' );
}
```

adicionar o filtro para o link do post:(será usada a primeira categoria)

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'nz_get_permalink' );

function nz_get_permalink( $permalink ) {
      global $post;

      if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
            $category = get_the_category();
            if ( isset( $category[ 0 ] ) ) {
                  $cat_slug = $category[ 0 ]->slug;
                  $permalink = trailingslashit( get_home_url() ) . trailingslashit( $cat_slug ) . $post->post_name;
            }
      }
      return $permalink;
}
```

redirecionar para nova url:(apenas é necessario se voce quiser redirecionar permanentemente visto que a permalink predefenida continua valendo)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'nz_redirect_posts', 100 );

function nz_redirect_posts() {
      global $wp_query;
      if ( $wp_query->get( 'name' ) && is_singular( 'post' ) && !$wp_query->get( 'category_name' ) ) {
            $permalink = get_permalink( $wp_query->post );
            wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
            exit;
      }

}
```